# Unable to add wysiwyg editor in Bootstrap container

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

I am trying to develop a admin page for my own blog cms like wp.

however i am unable to add wysiwyg editor in my admin page

```
<div class="box-inner">

         <style type="text/javascript"> $('#editor').wysiwyg();</style> /* this is editor */


        <div class="box-header well" data-original-title="">
            <h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>  Add Article</h2>

            <div class="box-icon">

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-minimize btn-round btn-default"><i
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-close btn-round btn-default"><i
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the editor works, but your script-tag is corrupt:

```
<style type="text/javascript"> $('#editor').wysiwyg();</style> /* this is editor */
```

Should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $('#editor').wysiwyg(); /* this is editor */
</script>
```